# android UI operation after receiving data from websocket server

Tags: java, android, websocket

Supposet my websocket server sends `data` to my android client which is defined as given below

```
public class ClientConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private void connectWebSocket() {
        URI uri;

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                                DO_MY_UI_CHANGES(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }
```

Now let say I want to Update my main threads UI element after receiving data from server. As of now I know that `DO_MY_UI_CHANGES(s)` wont work because we are trying to modify main threads element in this thread which isnt allowed in android.

Please suggest me something so that I can make call to DO_MY_UI_CHANGES.

Comment: Start by reading the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html  It talks about exactly what you're trying to do... specifically the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Look if I call .execute() method then surely whatever I wrote in onPostExecute will get reflected on the UI.

But what if I got message from server, then in that case onMessage will fire. Can you elaborate what will happen next

Comment: When your message comes back from the server, it goes into `onPostExecute`... what happens after that is in your hands.

Comment: ohh, then I must recheck my code. If you can check plz just have look at my code here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887542/run-postexecute-on-receiving-message-from-websocket-server"

if there's something wrong i am doing then please comment

Comment: @JeremyMiller onPostExecute method is not executing after receiving message from server. I checked that by putting log in onMessage and onPostExecute.

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong.  Give me some time to put the example together.

Comment: Oh, better yet, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607429/onmessage-event-in-websocket-client-is-not-getting-fired .  I didn't catch you were using something non-native to Android (my bad).  The AsyncTask may be causing some issues.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Tell me one thing if I use java-websocket library to build my Android websocket client, then will it be okay if I user Javax.Websocket package to build my java Webserver running in glassfish